# How to extend "Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed" to, say, five seconds

Tags: jestjs

I have uncontrollable asynchronous tear down that may, sometimes, take more than one second. So every now-and-then I get this jest message and its annoying.

Is there an option I can set to allow Jest to wait a bit longer? Say 5 seconds.

Comment: You can see all of Jest's options on https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Of course I did. Did I miss it?

Comment: My point being: given that it's not listed there, then doesn't that answer your question? You can also look at the [implementation](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/3a85065fe5604655e1337ffc1631f9999722c821/packages/jest-cli/src/cli/index.ts#L136-L148), where it's clearly hard-coded.

Comment: It's never really a hard no, just a _not currently_: you could fork Jest, or raise an issue/PR to get that value exposed to configuration (or see if it's already in progress).

Comment: yes, I am considering

Comment: @jonrsharpe What's with the revert edit?

Comment: Answers don't belong in questions, either write an actual answer below or delete the question. See [answer].

Comment: It was not an answer. It's additional observation.